# Outlet with ground wire attached to socket ground and neutral

Tags: wiring, receptacle, grounding

I am replacing some sockets with new sockets, that also contain USB charging receptacles. I have done this before. The question I have is with one of my outlets in my rec room (built in 2007, electrician did wiring originally).

Upon removal of one of the old grounded outlets, I noticed that the ground wire was connected to the ground screw AND the neutral screw. I thought this was odd. So I connected the new outlet the way I think it is supposed to be; two blacks to hot, two whites to neutral and one ground to ground. That resulted in that outlet and none of the downstream outlets working at all.

I reconnected the old outlet with the "proper" ground to see if that was the cause. Nope. It would not work at all (either outlet) unless the ground wire was connected to the neutral and the ground.

I am not sure if this is how it is supposed to be or why it is that way. I basically reinstalled the old receptacle how it was to avoid any problems but am not sure why it's like that. I also did install a new receptacle in the same room on another wall and it works perfectly. The ground was not wired to the neutral, only to the ground screw on that one.

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Can you post photos of the wiring inside the box with the "grounded neutral" receptacle?

Comment: Sorry. I have it all back together. Will do when I am back home. But to describe it, the end of the ground wire is around the ground screw on the receptacle, and then further down the ground wire is attached to the neutral screw. Further up from that is a wire not with two ground wires attached. So the two wires, go into a wire nut. Then one ground wire comes out of the tip of that wire nut and connects as I describe above. If that's not clear, I will get a pic tonight asap.

Comment: I am wondering if this was a jury rigged switch loop. Are the outlets on a switched circuit? Definitely not up to code if built in 07

Comment: If the ground wire is connected to the neutral screw, where is the neutral wire connected?

Comment: @EdBeal my guess is the "electrician" engineered a non-approved UNSAFE method of repairing a neutral opened by a drywall screw.

Comment: The neutral is connected to the neutral holes.

Comment: You might want to try to back trace and see which outlet deviates from the standard and why...

Comment: I agree with Tyson.  The neutral for the circuit was probably damaged, and the electrician is using the grounding conductor as a neutral.  This could be dangerous, and should be repaired properly.

Comment: Sounds like lots of work and cash. What is the risk? Fire?

Comment: Basically you don't have a ground. It's being used as the return path. So it includes any risk associated with not having a ground. If anything came loose or any connection down the line were to, everything connected to this phony ground would become hot - waiting to start a fire or zap someone. Don't worry too much though, many older homes do not have grounds at all and you're gone this far no issues. But it needs to be fixed, it'll only confuse everyone down the line and cause problems.

Comment: Honestly, I wish I hadn't stumbled across it. It's been fine for almost 10 years. There are several down circuit outlets that would be affected if I stopped the circuit in front of the problem. I will check all the upstream outlets, but if I can't find anything, I'm not sure I'm interested in tearing up the walls to find the issue. Damn. Too bad you can't trust "professionals"

Comment: I disagree with @TFK. If nothing else is broken or breaks, you probably won't electrocute anyone or start a fire. However, if the ground is also disconnected for some reason, *anything on the downstream (disconnected) part of the circuit would become an electrocution/fire hazard* -- this means any metal on appliances, tools, electrical boxes, screws on the face plates, etc. Given there's already clearly bad workmanship done by someone who either doesn't know what they're doing or was willfully negligent, I wouldn't trust any of the rest of the work to be either correct or safe.

Comment: As a safe (and cheaper) alternative, but not a fix for the issue, you could use a GFCI for the circuit. This would detect any potential difference and work as a safety. Also, the true fix might not be that costly once the final location of the breakage is located.

Comment: OK. I'll go looking for a simple solution. If not, I'll look into that GFCI. There is actually a GFCI down there by the bar sink, which is closer to the panel than the affected outlet. I think it's on a separate circuit but will double check. Interestingly, I don't really "need" the affected outlet but do need the ones downstream.

Answer (score 3):

Misusing ground as neutral is a code violation.  It's the work of a hack electrician trying to get a job across the finish line, or other tradesman who severed a neutral by accident and hacked it so no one would notice.

I would search each receptacle box in that circuit for a reason for a neutral problem. Most wiring problems are at terminations.  If you find none, I would find the next box back on the cable run (that is still hot), and disconnect the cable there. Whatever broke the neutral may have also nicked the hot.

If the electrician did this, then every connection in your house needs review.  You know how to do receptacles!